# tkinter "unknown option "-padx" "

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a project using `tkinter` and I wanted to change button styles to make it look better, but when I start import `tkinter.tkk` the code starts messing up.

I could not find any clear solution on the Internet and also when I start another code with both `tkinter` and `tkinter.tkk` imported it works fine.

Here is the working code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
 
 
root = Tk()
 

root.geometry('100x100')
 

style = Style()
 
 
style.configure('TButton', font =
               ('calibri', 10, 'bold', 'underline'),
                foreground = 'red')

btn1 = Button(root, text = 'Quit !',
                  style = 'TButton',
             command = root.destroy)
 
btn1.grid(row = 0, column = 3, padx = 100)
 
btn2 = Button(root, text = 'Click me !', command = None)
btn2.grid(row = 1, column = 3, pady = 10, padx = 100)
 
root.mainloop()
```

And here is the code that has a problem:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *


window= Tk()
window.title('customers information')


e = Entry(window, width=50)

button1 = Button(window,text='1',padx=40,pady=40)
button2 = Button(window,text='2',padx=40,pady=40)
button3 = Button(window,text='3',padx=40,pady=40)

button4 = Button(window,text='4',padx=40,pady=40)
button5 = Button(window,text='5',padx=40,pady=40)
button6 = Button(window,text='6',padx=40,pady=40)

button7 = Button(window,text='7',padx=40,pady=40)
button8 = Button(window,text='8',padx=40,pady=40)
button9 = Button(window,text='9',padx=40,pady=40)

button0 = Button(window,text='0',padx=40,pady=40)

buttoneq = Button(window,text='=',padx=40,pady=40,fg='black',bg="silver")
buttonplus = Button(window,text='+',padx=40,pady=40,fg='black',bg='silver')
buttonminus = Button(window,text='-',padx=40,pady=40,fg='black',bg='silver')
buttonclear = Button(window,text='C',padx=40,pady=40,fg='black',bg='silver')


button1.grid(row=1,column=1)
button2.grid(row=1,column=2)
button3.grid(row=1,column=3)

button4.grid(row=2,column=1)
button5.grid(row=2,column=2)
button6.grid(row=2,column=3)

button7.grid(row=3,column=1)
button8.grid(row=3,column=2)
button9.grid(row=3,column=3)

button0.grid(row=4,column=1)

buttonplus.grid(row=4,column=2)
buttonminus.grid(row=4,column=3)
buttoneq.grid(row=5,column=2)
buttonclear.grid(row=5,column=1)



e.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=5,padx=10,pady=10)

window.mainloop()
```

And the exception :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\lcc_zarkos\Desktop\UKIYO-dataframer\gui-tkinter.py", line 12, in <module>
    button1 = Button(window,text='1',padx=40,pady=40)
  File "C:\Users\lcc_zarkos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 612, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, "ttk::button", kw)
  File "C:\Users\lcc_zarkos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 557, in __init__
    tkinter.Widget.__init__(self, master, widgetname, kw=kw)
  File "C:\Users\lcc_zarkos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2569, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-padx"
```

Please let me know if you have any solutions.

Comment: I suggest importing only what You need and not use `*`: something like this: `from tkinter import Tk, Button, Entry, Frame` and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know, Tkinter Entry widget can have width property only AS if you want to position the entry widget then use padx and pady however if you want to resize the entry widget then use ipadx and ipady.

```
from tkinter import *

#Create an instance of tkinter window
root= Tk()
root.geometry("600x450")

e= Entry(root, width= 20)
e.pack(ipadx=30, ipady= 30)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

#### You must [**`pad` the elements**](https://riptutorial.com/tkinter/example/29713/grid--) in the `grid()` method.

This:

```py
button1 = Button(window, text='1', padx=40, pady=40)
...
button1.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

Must be done like this:

```py
button1 = Button(window, text='1')
...
button1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=40, pady=40)
```

---

**Also you should avoid importing `tkinter` and `tkinter.ttk` at the same time** using `from ... import *`: when you type `Button(...)`, this calls the `tkinter.ttk.Button` class instead of the `tkinter.Button` class. And this class doesn't support the `fg` and `bg` arguments. So prefer removing the line

```py
from tkinter.ttk import *
```

This will avoid this error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lcc_zarkos\Desktop\UKIYO-dataframer\gui-tkinter.py", line 25, in <module>
    buttoneq = Button(window,text='=',fg='black',bg="silver")
  File "C:\Users\lcc_zarkos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 612, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, "ttk::button", kw)
  File "C:\Users\lcc_zarkos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 557, in __init__
    tkinter.Widget.__init__(self, master, widgetname, kw=kw)
  File "C:\Users\lcc_zarkos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2567, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-fg"
```

---

If you still want to import `tkinter.ttk`, import it, for example, like that:

```py
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
```

Comment: then how can i change the size of the button ?

Comment: as i know when you pad the button in the grid method it will just push aside the buttons

Comment: You will find information about buttons and size [**here**](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/button.html) and about grid and padding [**here**](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/grid.html) (tkinter documentation).

Answer (score 0):

for button you can't add padding to it using confige(padx = 10)

but you need to add it to the grid function.
but for label you can .

```
button = tkinter.Button(text = "add", command = calculte)
button.grid(column = 3, row =  0, pady = (5,5))

result = tkinter.Label(text = "= ")
# you can add in gride function 
result.grid(column = 4, row = 0, padx = (10,0))
# and you can also add it here 
result.config(padx = 10)
```